# Search for video files in sharepoint 2010 search

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, relevance

I was just wondering if there's any way to run a search on a sharepoint 2010 intranet site which will return all the video files.There's a requirement for the same and advanced search only provides for filters like ms word docs, ppts etc. Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

If you have a specific extension, you can use in your search query box the Fileextension:mp4 or filetype:mp4 assuming the video are stored in mp4 format.

You can also create a search scope that will add any extension required (wmv, avi, mpg, mp4, flv, ...) so that you / your end-users can pick the search scopes for the video.

Please keep in mind that unless you have a specific ifilter for the video file (are there any on the market ?) the search will only be done on the metadata that are attached to the list item holding the video. Ensure that your video have their title, description, abstract, author, etc. field properly filled.